# Calling a class in a different sub-project using eclipse

Tags: java

I have a project where I am trying to call a class that is in another sub-project but it is resulting in a compile error.

This is how my project structure looks:

[image]

I am trying to call a class `DownLoadFactory` from the `utilcmrujar` sub-project to a class `B` that is under the `crmuwar` sub-project.

---

This is how I imported the package in class `B` under the `crmuwar` sub-project but it produces a compile error:

[image]

---

Would I actually have to sub-project `utilcmrujar` into a `jar` file and call it as a dependency?

Comment: Your Java packages should be inside the "Java Resources" folder in this view. Show us what is inside it?

Comment: Those "packages" are sub-projects? Not Java "packages"...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto correct, sorry will change it to subprojects.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Eclipse.  Simply add the utilcmrujar folder to your classpath by right clicking on the older and selecting *Build Path > Use as Source Folder*:

[image]

Repeat the same step for each of your source folders.

Inside of your utilcmrujar source folders, you should have com/south/smdw/crm/webutils and com/south/smdw/crm/data folders, based on your *package* and *import* statements.  DownloadFactory.java should be in com/south/smdw/crm/data (based on the import statement) and the file you are editing should be in com/south/smdw/crm/webutils (based on your package declaration).

Comment: Hi I have tried that but still same error that package does not exist.

Comment: I added details to the answer, based on your code.  Your source folders should contain com/south/smdw/crm/... sub-folders.